# Как объявить метод обработчиком нажатий

Tags: android

У меня есть три кнопки, я нахожу их так:

```
    tab_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_tab_1);
    tab_2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_tab_2);
    tab_3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_tab_3);
```

После этого я пытаюсь присвоить им обработчик нажатий:

```
    tab_1.setOnClickListener(onTabClick);
    tab_2.setOnClickListener(onTabClick);
    tab_3.setOnClickListener(onTabClick);
```

Но мне выдает ошибку:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'onTabClick'

Вот сам метод:

```
public void onTabClick(View v) {
}
```

Как назначить этот метод обработчиком нажатий через Java код?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Вам надо создать переменную (поле класса) с типом `View.OnClickListener`:

   ```
   View.OnClickListener onTabClick = new OnClickListener()
   {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v)
       {       
       }
   };
   ```
2. Или использовать анонимный класс:

   ```
   tab_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v)
   {
   });
   ```
3. Или заставить активити/фрагмент реализовать этот интерфейс переопределив метод `onClick` в активити/фрагменте

   ```
   public class ActivityMain extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
   {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        });
   }
   ```

И теперь назначать обработчик можно просто ссылкой на `this`:

```
tab_1.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: А можно это как-то в отдельный метод вынести?

Comment: Не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду.

Comment: Мне нужно будет вызвать этот метод через Java код, для этого мне нужно, чтобы метод не был скрыт областью видимости от остального кода, а был как обычный метод `онCkick` в классе.

Comment: @bukashka101 я подсобрал варианты в своём ответе, там вынос есть.

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите таким образом программно вызвать нажатие на кнопку?.. Это делается так: `button.performClick()`. При этом вызовется присвоенный кнопке обработчик нажатий.

Comment: ЮрийСПб, нет, не так. Потом мне нужно будет передать этому методу `View`, но обработчик присвоить нельзя.

Comment: @LapshinDmitry, простите, но Юрий первый дал нужный мне ответ. Но Вам плюсик я поставил =).

Comment: @bukashka101 я и не спорю, я просто считаю, что если программист будет видеть более полный инструментарий, то сможет лучше понять, что и зачем он использует.

Comment: В методе обработчике вы можете обращаться к полям класса активити (т.е. в View элементам) или к final переменным метода, в коем определён анонимный класс (2 вариант). Либо можно создать отдельный класс (как у @LapshinDmitry в первом варианте) и через конструктор передать ссылки на View

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно передать объект, реализующий конкретный метод, реализуя интерфейс `OnClickListener`. Его получить можно многими способами:

**Во-первых**, честно написать отдельный класс с таким методом:

```
class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    /* Конструктор, если нужен */

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ....
    }
}
```

и далее

```
OnClickListener listener = new ButtonClickListener();
```

**Во-вторых**, анонимный класс, как в других ответах:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ....
    }
}
```

У этого подхода плюс в том, что можно захватить (capture) локальные финальные переменные. В первом варианте их придётся передавать через конструктор.

**В-третьих** можно просто сделать `YourActivity implements OnClickListener` и написать метод. Учтите, что так много разных обработчиков не написать, будет один общий.

**В-четвёртых** (но для Android не подойдёт) с Java 8 можно вообще кратко:

```
OnClickListener listener = (OnClickListener) (v) -> {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`setOnClickListener` требует в качестве аргумента объект класса порождённого от `OnClickListener`. Который можно создать на месте
примерно так:

```
tab_1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ....
    }
});
```

Если обработчики одинаковые, возможно лучше создать один объект на всех, а потом передать его:

```
OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ....
    }
};
tab_1.setOnClickListener(listener);
tab_2.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - прописать в xml файле разметки, для каждой кнопки, параметр:

```
android:onClick="onTabClick"
```

АПДЕЙТ:

Через код можно так:

```
tab_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

//тут уже вызывать метод свой

    });
```

Comment: А через Java код как?