# Почему не работает атрибут разметки android:onClick в фрагменте?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. У меня есть фрагмент и кнопка. Как мне правильно вызвать метод `sendMail()` при нажатии на кнопку. И еще почему подсвечивается создание экземпляра Mail (Unreachable statment)?

Вот код:

```
public class TabFragment1 extends Fragment {
private Mail m ;
private ImageButton imgSend;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_fragment_1, container, false);
    m = new Mail("********@gmail.com", "*******");
}


public void sendEmail(View view){
    String[] toArr = {"toemail1@domain1.tld"}; // This is an array, you can add more emails, just separate them with a coma
    m.setTo(toArr); // load array to setTo function
    m.setFrom("fromEmail@domain.tld"); // who is sending the email
    m.setSubject("subject");
    m.setBody("your message goes here");

    try {
        m.addAttachment("/sdcard/myPicture.jpg");  // path to file you want to attach
        if(m.send()) {
            // success
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // failure
            Toast.makeText(getActivity() ,"Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // some other problem
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "There was a problem sending the email.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Всё, что после `return` выполнено не будет никогда. Так что поместите всё что после `return` до него.

Comment: Это невнимательность, а вот с вызов метода sendMail волнует больше(В activity норм пашет)??

Comment: А почему бы не поместить кнопку в сам фрагмент, а не в активити?..

Comment: Она у меня в фрагменте, но вот проблема с вызовом метода.

Comment: У вас слушатель, что ли, через разметку указан?.. Если да - то не делайте так. Не надо. Назначьте его программно.

Comment: Никогда не устанавливайте слушатели в разметке. Никогда в жизи. Инженера Google, который это придумал нужно сжечь на костре.

Comment: Я вот не понимаю что мне передать в метод.какой параметр при вызове:imgSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                sendEmail();

            }
        });При током обработчике выдает ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Атрибут `android:onClick` в разметке работает только для слушателей нажатия на кнопку в активити, для фрагмента нужно устанавливать слушатель программно. О нескольких способах назначить слушатель программно читайте [этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461428/177345)

Unreachable statment - недостижимое объявление, код за оператором return не будет выполнен, так как произойдет выход из метода.